# How to add some javascript code under the post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to add some javascript code after the content and before the related news links but my javascript code shown **after** the related news.

I try to this with add my code here :
themes\themes_name\content_single.php :

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>

    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php accesspress_basic_posted_on(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
<div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'accesspress-basic' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<div class="ads-baroot ads-desc">
**my Codes here...**
</div>
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking. I don't see any JS in this code. What is exactly your issue?

Comment: My javascripts code run well and shown my result but show after the related news links, I need to show my code before the related news links

Comment: where is related news,content and finally js??

Answer (score 0):

The Related news is probably parsed in `<?php the_content(); ?>`, your javascript-code is below that. Therefore the javascript result is displayed below the related posts.

Answer (score 0):

Create your script file and add in theme default js folder and call in your theme function.php

```
function custom_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'customjquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customjquery.js', array(), '0001', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_scripts' );
```